# Google App Engine failing to load after adding Firebase to existing Google Cloud project

Tags: firebase, authentication, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I am following an official Google [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/building-app/adding-firebase) to add Firebase Authentication to my existing web service running on a Google App Engine (GAE).

The first step involves adding Firebase to my existing Google Cloud project (that is running the web service with the GAE). However, right after doing this, the App Engine page in the Google Cloud Console fails to load (see screenshot below):

[image]

Additionally (and I believe non-exhaustively), this has also reset the billing account of my Google Cloud project:

[image]

Are there known bugs when adding Firebase to an existing Google Cloud project or am I missing something? I have looked online for a solution to this issue but to no avail.

Alternatively, the documentation mentions that:

> You can also choose to use a Firebase account with a different name, not associated with your existing Google Cloud project.

which I think could circumvent the problem. However, I would like to understand why the first suggested procedure leads to issues.

Comment: What happens when you click on "Manage Billing Accounts"?

Answer (score 1):

You need to activate your Cloud Billing account to use it and define which services you are using. It can be linked to one or more projects that you have. Project usage is charged to the linked Cloud Billing account.

As this document stated:

> Important: If you have a project that is not linked to an active, valid Cloud Billing account, you will not be able to use the products and services enabled in your project. This is true even if your project only uses Google Cloud services that are free.

There is a way to [Check if billing is enabled on a project](https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/modify-project#confirm_billing_is_enabled_on_a_project)

I found this blog post that can assist the possible set up to fix your issue [Moving a Firebase project to a GCP Organization](https://medium.com/google-cloud/moving-a-firebase-project-to-a-gcp-organization-860c46ff416) It provides a step-by-step procedure with images samples in it.

Other Information that might help:

- [Add Firebase project to GCP project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69174697/add-firebase-project-to-gcp-project/69184608#69184608)

Hope it helps